# Does this code have problems with converting date and time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

```
if picture[:latitude] && picture[:longitude]

  parsed_date_time = DateTime.rfc3339(picture[:picture_timestamp]).to_s(:db)
  timezone = Timezone.lookup(picture[:latitude], picture[:longitude])
  date_obj = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[timezone.name].parse(parsed_date_time)

  date_with_offset = DateTime.new(date_obj.year, date_obj.month, date_obj.day, date_obj.hour, date_obj.min, date_obj.sec, date_obj.zone).to_s

  @dailypost.picture_timestamp = Time.zone.parse(date_with_offset)
end
```

I have the following situation. The client side sends the EXIF ​​data of the photo to the server. Moreover, any date (originalDateTime, dateTime or digitizedDateTime) is sent in the rfc3339 format with a zeroed offset (for example: 2017-20-10T12: 50: 30 + 00: 00, why is it this way and not otherwise, another question. I cannot change it now).

(And when I get a dateTime with an offset of zero, it is simply because the client side is zeroing the offset, while simply concatenating with the date and time with an offset of zero. Just a concatenating. And that why I just parsing date and time from rfc3339, and then I create dateTime object with a particular timeZone)

On the server side, ABOUT the following happens. We calculate timeZone based on coordinates, create a date-time object with the desired offset, then bring this date to the default time zone on the server (Central Daylight Time) and then save it to the database. I cannot change now the format in which we receive the date and in which we save it to the database. Further from the database, this date is taken out, converted again into the rfc3339 format, and sent to the client side.

I think there is definitely some mistake here, with the conversion of date and time, which I cannot see now. The problem is that I was told there are photos that are uploading with the wrong date. Is there anything at all valid in all these actions?

Answer (score 0):

Extract the code above into a function like `def get_local_datetime(lat, lon, timestamp)` and then you can write a test case. Given the lat/lon in SantaClara and an rfc3339 timestamp you should know the output of that function - does it match?

Finally, rfc3339 is an exif thing. I hate it too. And, some cameras output it without any timezone statement. It sucks.

Comment: You are right, I poorly formulated the question. The problem is that I was told there are photos that are uploading with the wrong date. About extracting the code above into a function, I did that. And when I test it, it seems to work.

Comment: As I mentioned. Som cameras output with no timezone identifier, but the time is local to the camera already. So perhaps the conversion is unnecessary

Comment: You’ll want to test that extracted function with a “problem” photo.

Answer (score 0):

Think of DateTime as a date with time and a timezone, by doing `DateTime.rfc3339(picture[:picture_timestamp])` you already have the rfc date converted to a datetime with timezone, if your EXIF is returning all dates with +00:00 it means that they are registered with zeroed offsets, meaning that the time is correct, is just presented in other timezone or in the worst case, they aren't registered.
In this case you should create a new DateTime with the original values and add the timezone, in your case

```rb
offset = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[timezone.name].formatted_offset
date_with_offset = DateTime.new(parsed_date_time.year, parsed_date_time.month, parsed_date_time.day, parsed_date_time.hour, parsed_date_time.min, parsed_date_time.sec, offset)
```

On the other hand, rails will use the default timezone of the app in your config/application.rb file to present and convert dates from your database, so if your app is configured in CDT you just need a correct datetime object to pass to the db and rails will handle the convertion for the saving, since your dates already have timezones from the parsing, no need to worry about it *(it would be different is you are asking the user for the date and need the timezone to make sense of it)*, depending on the database these would be handle as datetime objects or integer timestamps, but most likely without a timezone(+0). For the part of presenting the date to the user, if you want to have different timezones for each user, you should have this field in your database and use it in the presentation part, something like `Time.at(@dailypost.picture_timestamp).in_time_zone(current_user.timezone)`, where Time.at is the datetime since a timestamp *(seconds since epoc)* and current_user.timezone is the name of timezone, eg: 'Sidney', or maybe just calculate the timezone if you have access to the lat and lon like in your example.

refs:

- [rfc3339](https://medium.com/easyread/understanding-about-rfc-3339-for-datetime-formatting-in-software-engineering-940aa5d5f68a)
- [timezones](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones)
- [db handle of time](https://makandracards.com/makandra/646-how-rails-and-mysql-are-handling-time-zones)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think I poorly formulated the question. I just want to mention that exif actually not saving any time zones. And when I get a dateTime with an offset of zero, it is simply because the client side is zeroing the offset, while simply concatenating with the date and time with an offset of zero. Just concatenating. And that why I just parsing date and time from rfc3339, and then create dateTime object with a particular timeZone.